# How to split audio (side a and side b) using librosa

Tags: python, librosa

I'm trying to use librosa to split a stereo audio file into separate channels. I have this code:

```py
import librosa

audio, sr = librosa.load('trumpet.wav')

canal_esquerdo, canal_direito = librosa.effects.split_stereo(audio)

librosa.output.write_wav('canal_esquerdo.wav', canal_esquerdo, sr)
librosa.output.write_wav('canal_direito.wav', canal_direito, sr)
```

but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "audio.py", line 7, in <module>
    canal_esquerdo, canal_direito = librosa.effects.split_stereo(audio)
AttributeError: module 'librosa.effects' has no attribute 'split_stereo'
```

What is wrong with the code? Is it possible to split the audio using librosa? If so, how?

Comment: Where did you read that you can use `librosa.effects.split_stereo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you separate each channel of a two channel wav file into two different files using wavio? or another library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275725/how-do-you-separate-each-channel-of-a-two-channel-wav-file-into-two-different-fi)

Comment: I'm not sure if librosa is the right tool for this purpose.

Comment: I need to separate the lines from the audio, I don't know if that would be possible, I took this code example from another forum that had no more answers, the link above does not separate the lines

Comment: Do you mean by "separate the lines" something different than "separate left and right channel"?

Comment: Yes, let me put it in a better way here, I have an audio with two people who are talking on side A and side B. I want to separate these audios, would it be possible?

Comment: Does [the documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/multichannel.html) answer your question?

Comment: I edited the question to [remove noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) and ask a question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means exactly what it says: `.split_stereo` isn't provided here, so that can't be used to split the stereo file.

To find out how to use a library for a given task, do not guess at names for functions - **search for, and read, documentation**.

The [relevant documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/multichannel.html) explains:

> When working with multi-channel signals, we may choose to skip the default down-mixing step by specifying `mono=False` in the call to `librosa.load`, as in the following:
>
> ```
> import librosa
>
> # Get the "high-quality" multi-channel version of
> # an example track
> filename = librosa.ex('trumpet', hq=True)
>
> # Load as multi-channel data
> y_stereo, sr = librosa.load(filename, mono=False)
> ```
>
> The resulting object now has two dimensions instead of one, with `y_stereo.shape == (N_channels, N_samples)`. This way, we can access the first channel as `y_stereo[0]`, the second channel as `y_stereo[1]`, and so on if there are more than two channels.

That is to say: librosa does not treat "stereo" as a special case; as long as `mono=False` is specified, loading just gives a 2d array representing however many channels there are.

Adapting that to the original code:

```
import librosa

audio, sr = librosa.load('trumpet.wav', mono=False)

librosa.output.write_wav('canal_esquerdo.wav', audio[0], sr)
librosa.output.write_wav('canal_direito.wav', audio[1], sr)
```

Answer (score -2):

Recommend using `split_to_mono()` per [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown).

#### For example:

```py
left, right = audio.split_to_mono()
```